# Newbie: Using a variable as the rhs argument to the dot operator?

Tags: java

I have a list of objects and I'll need to access a specific one based off of random user input corresponding to an id. My limited knowledge at this point led me to something like:

```
String id; 
if(id.equals("apple")){ //fixed silly error, thanks
    return objectList.id.memberName; 
} //etc...
```

Is this possible, or is there a better approach?

Comment: A word to the wise on comparing strings in Java: you should use `equals` to compare strings, not `==` (the code you posted with only `=` won't even compile because it's assigning to `id` in the if condition, not comparing).  In other words, the second line of your code should be `if (id.equals("apple")) {`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

It works like a telephone directory - you put in keys and values, and use the key to look up a value (much like you'd use someone's name to look up their number in a telephone directory.)

Your example also wouldn't work at all, because you're using = in the if statement, which is an assignment statement rather than an equality check. == is what you were probably trying to get, but in this case you shouldn't use that either - instead use `.equals()` which you should always use when strings are concerned.)

Comment: Yes this looks like what I should use, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<String, SomeValueObject> myMap = new HashMap<String, SomeValueObject>();
myMap.put("apple", value);
String id;
if (id.equals("apple")) {
    return myMap.get("apple");
}
```

Essentially you instantiate a HashMap that has two parts to it; a Key and a Value (respectively. When I do `myMap.get("apple")`, it searches for the KEY "apple". I did `myMap.put("apple", value)` which makes the Key "apple" be mapped to a certain value that you want.

Also you need to use `id.equals("apple")` because a String is an object, and if you tried `id == "apple"` (which I think you meant), it will not work because it will not compare the value of the String but rather the address of it.

Answer (score 0):

@berry120 has provided a practical answer.  In general, it sounds like you want to lookup values based on some key.  Look at the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface and what the JDK offers for concrete implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The *value* of a variable is only available at run time. On the other hand, a *variable name* must be known at compile time. So no, you cannot do this exactly the way you are asking. Using a `Map` will probably be the best solution to your problem.